# A problem about the graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A class of 37 is to be divided into teams, and each student in
the class must be a member of exactly one team. However, each
student dislikes three of their classmates. Dislike between students
need not be mutual. How many teams must be created so that no
student is the teammate of someone they dislik?

I have no idea about this problem which seems trick. Could anyone give some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Mees gives a beautiful answer which adresses the fact that the minimal amount of team depends on the way the arrows stand in the graph. On the other hand the question doesn’t ask for minimality, thus one could potentially build 37 teams and answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We cannot answer this question without further information.

On one extreme case, if each boy only dislikes girls and vice versa, 2 teams suffice (boys vs. girls).

In the worst case, you need 7 teams: numbering 7 of the kids $0, \ldots, 6$ and letting kid $i$ dislike kids $i+1, i+2, i+3$ (modulo 7) gives a copy of $K_7$, which requires 7 colors (teams) just to satisfy those 7 kids. <s>However, 7 teams is always enough by [Brooks' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem)</s>.

**Edit:** Misha Lavrov in the comments correctly points out that my application of Brooks' Theorem was incorrect. He offers an alternative explanation: the (symmetrized) dislike graph is [6-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)), and by the information given on that page (specifically the equivalence of the two historical definitions) it is easy to see that this makes the graph 7-colorable.

Comment: Brooks's theorem is not enough because the maximum degree could exceed $6$: you could have a kid who is hated by everybody. On the other hand, since the average degree in any subgraph is at most $6$, the graph is $6$-degenerate, so it is $7$-colorable.

Comment: @bof, unfortunately I don't have access to anything but the phone app for a few days, where editing is nearly impossible to get right (hence the current botch job). Please feel free to correct it if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

If we draw the directed graph with vertices players and an arrow from $p$ to $q$ iff $p$ dislikes $q$, then $d_{\text{out}}(v) = 3$ for all vertices and $|V|=37$. A team assigmnent is a vertex colouring where two endpoints of an arrow must have a distinct colour.

I don't know any theorems on colouring numbers of directed graphs in relation to (out-)degrees, though. But you might?